# iTunes alternative on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, music, ubuntu, media-player

I like iTunes, but unfortunately it is not available for Linux/Ubuntu.

Some features I am looking for:

- Playlists
- Ability to change song from taskbar
- Album covers
- CD import
- Notification when the song is changing

Comment: No need about iPad, iPhone or iPod support?

Comment: @Fractaliste Nope. Don't own one, I prefer using androids.

Comment: This question is too broad. There are a LOT of players in this field and there is nothing in your question that really narrows it down enough to give a specific recommendation of one package over another. This is just going to be a popularity contest between the biggest players in the field. Can you give us anything in the way of a a specific problem that you haven't solved with the obvious choices? As asked this is [much better serviced by alternativeto.net](http://alternativeto.net/software/itunes/?platform=linux).

Comment: @Caleb, perhaps this is too broad, but at least it actually *received answers.*  [My own question](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/35219/22795) is quite specific but has sadly received no answers at all, even with a bounty.  :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[**Quod Libet**](http://code.google.com/p/quodlibet/) (License: GPL v2) seems to have all features you mentioned:

- playlists are supported (can be exported as M3U and PLS via plugin)
- covers are displayed (it looks for a file in the current folder named, e.g., `folder.jpg`) (there is also a plugin that can download covers)
- it comes with a notification plugin
- it comes with a plugin for Sound Menu integration
- new tracks can be added via file, folder, URL

It’s based on GTK+, and is [available in Ubuntu’s packages](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/quodlibet).

QL is a great piece of software. You can have ten thousands of tracks in your library and you will still have good performance.

Elaborate [search](http://quodlibet.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guide/searching.html) options: You can use regular expressions, boolean *and* (`&`), *or* (`|`), *not* (`!`) (+ *greater/lower than* (`>`, `<`) for numerical values), search for custom tags and their values, search for playcount, rating, track length, ….

It also comes with (and nicely integrates via context menu) the tag editor **Ex Falso**.

I don’t have an *Apple iPod*, but friends could successfully copy music from my QL to their device.

Comment: I recommended it also as [Linux music player for huge music collection](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/4081/60).

Comment: Does it allow for *playlist* syncing to Android?  Specifically, not storing multiple copies of a song because it is in multiple playlists, but instead storing one copy and referencing that copy from multiple playlists?  If so you could [mention it on my question](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/35219/22795) and collect the bounty.  :)

Answer (score 4):

In default Ubuntu installation, there's [Rhythmbox](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Rhythmbox) that includes at least almost all features you want.

List of requirements from the question:

- **Playlists**: [yes](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Rhythmbox#Playlists).
- **Ability to change song from taskbar**: yes, with [plugin](https://code.google.com/p/rhythmtray/) (I haven't used this)
- **Album covers**: yes.
- **CD import**: [yes](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Rhythmbox#Importing_Audio_CDs).
- **Notification when the song is changing**: yes (bubble)

It is obviously not as well designed as iTunes is. Rhythmbox have a long history (more than 10 years); that does not guarantee stability, but when I was using it, it was always stable and got things done.

[image: Screenshot from www.tuxjournal.net]

Comment: Obviously not as well designed as iTunes!? I use Rhythmbox and iTunes a lot, and greatly prefer Rhythmbox, especially to the new iTunes interface.

Answer (score 3):

My choice would be [Guayadeque Music Player](https://www.guayadeque.org/index.php?p=/)

Guayadeque is included in Ubuntu repositories and can be installed through Ubuntu Software centre

[image: Guayadeque Music Player]
<sub>(source: [ubuntu.com](http://screenshots.ubuntu.com/screenshots/g/guayadeque/5010_large.png))</sub>

**Requested features**:

- Guayadeque supports dynamic or static play lists.
- Guayadeque comes with sys-try applet and have ability to change song
  from taskbar
- Album covers can be downloaded manually or automatically
- Guayadeque can import music from various sources including external
  media
- OSD Notification when the song is changing

[image: Guayadeque task bar applet]

**Additional features**

- Play mp3, ogg, flac, wma, mpc, mp4, ape, etc
- Allow to catalogue your music using labels. Any track, artist or
  album can have as many labels you want
- Suggest music using last.fm service
- Allow to subscribe to podcasts and download all new episodes
  automatically or manually

List of features can be found [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20140419015840/https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/quantal/guayadeque/)

Answer (score 0):

Although I have never tried it myself, I believe [Nightingale](http://getnightingale.com/) might be a good alternative, since it described in LinuxFormat as:

> The interface is reminiscent of the heyday if *iTunes*, back when it was about helping you organise your music and less about selling you stuff.

Since I haven't tried it myself, I don't know about some of the features you ask ( such as changing songs from the task bar ), but I think that may be good for you because of the iTunes-like interface. Here is a screenshot:
[image: Screenshot (on OSX)]

Answer (score -3):

I would still recommend [Rhythmbox](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Rhythmbox) -- I myself prefer it a lot to iTunes (at least the new iTunes), but:
*You can use iTunes on Linux*. It is not too hard to install with playonlinux. However, it is not recommended as a default music player, as it is slow to start and a bore to set up to look nice. Still, might be good to mention it, in case you just MUST use iTunes :)

Comment: Could you add a reference to the tool and maybe a screenshot? How does it meet with the requirements?

Comment: @MadTux Please make sure to include links for optimum answer quality. (I've just added one for you)