# Browser-based music player (self-hosted)

Tags: linux, web-apps, open-source, music, streaming

Locally, I have a huge music collection managed by [Quod Libet](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/180/60), which works great. Now I’d like to listen to all of my music from other computers, e.g. when visiting a friend.

I don’t want to stream it from my computer, so I’m looking for a Web application which I can install on my server.

#### Features:

- Require **login** for accessing the app.

  - Bonus: Allow several user accounts.
- It should support **MP3** and **OGG**.
- It should have no problems managing **30000-40000 tracks**.
- **Search** function (full text, and/or by title/artist/album).

  - Bonus: allow searching custom tags.
- **Playlists** (it would be great if I could create playlists "on the fly" from within the app).
- **Repeat** & **random** modes.
- Bonus: Allow downloading single tracks, or even all tracks of a playlist/album.
- Bonus: Show how much traffic was used in the current month.

#### Not needed:

- Upload function / synchronization (I’ll take care of uploading the music to my server, so the tool doesn’t need to do this)
- Tagging, renaming, deletion (I’ll upload only organized music).
- Nice design.

#### Formal requirements:

- It must be **Free/Libre Open Source Software**.
- It must run natively on a **GNU/Linux** server.

Comment: Still in alpha fase, but interesting is [Beatstream](http://www.beatstream.fi/). [Code on GitHub](https://github.com/Darep/Beatstream)

Comment: Found [GNU FM](http://gnu.io/fm/), but couldn’t test it yet.

Comment: @unor did you ever come around this?

Comment: @AngeloFuchs: No, not yet. When I find the time, I also want to look into [Music Player Daemon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Music_Player_Daemon) and one of the many supported [web clients](http://mpd.wikia.com/wiki/Clients#Web_Clients).

Comment: @unor, how can you get music to your devices without streaming? If you aren't at your machine, you *have* to steam, don't you?

Comment: @IronManMark20: Yes, but I don’t want to stream from my computer (making it a server, having to run 24/7), but from my Web server.

Answer (score 3):

A friend of mine has had a great experience with [Ampache](http://ampache.org). It is released under the Gpl v2, and has been in development for over 10 years. It has a clean looking interface for a web client.

To my knowledge, and based on their website, it meets all of your requirements and allows you to download songs. Usage data, I don't know.