# Linux music player for huge music collection

Tags: linux, gratis, music

This question seems silly, so easy to answer! Well... Hold on! What if I tell that my music folder is... 15GB.

I have Xubuntu 64 bit, Clementine isn't indexing all my songs. Banshee freezes when I import my library. Itunes is the only software that handled my music correctly when I was on windows and I don't want to use wine. What I want

- Music player that runs on Xubuntu 64 bit, natively.
- Free (not necessarily open source)
- Plays Mp3s mainly
- Capable of handling huge libraries, fast indexing, no lagging, no crashing, no missing songs, no freezing, no bugs. (**Well tested for its ability to handle big libraries**)
- No VLC or such, I know that VLC can play mp3s and may be able to handle big libraries, I'm looking for pure music player
- Ability to create playlist, create a library and so on.
- No CLI solutions  or Rythmbox or such, I want a full featured GUI if possible, like banshee.
- I would like to avoid KDE applications if possible.

Comment: I don't know what you are experiencing, but I haven't seen any problems with Clementine, and I have 85 GB of music.

Comment: @rumtscho I go to preferences, add new folder (which contains other folders) it doesn't import all of them, many songs are missing

Comment: the only two music players, to my knowledge, that handle 'bigger' libraries without 'glitching' are Rythmbox and Banshee. Why are you ruling out Rythmbox? And if Banshee is freezing there is something weird going on. You could try Quod Libet, I've no experience myself with it but I heared good things about it.

Comment: Guayadeque is my favourite! Works perfectly with my 50k+ collection on my weak orange pi plus.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I’m using [**Quod Libet**](https://github.com/quodlibet/quodlibet) with a music library of **170 GB** (~ 30000 tracks).

Its performance is outstanding. My PC is old and has weak hardware, but listing (or searching through) *all* those 30000 tracks only takes a few seconds (maybe 2-4 secs).

> Unlike some, Quod Libet will scale to libraries with tens of thousands of songs.

This good performance was one of the main reasons why I chose QL, but I’m very happy with all of its other features, too. It’s one of those rare pieces of software which I consider perfect for me, and I can recommend it whole-heartedly.

I’m using it daily for many years, and I can’t remember any serious issues. I never experienced missing songs or freezes. A few times in all those years it crashed (mabye 10 times), but these were individual cases which I could never reproduce.

About your other requirements:

- it runs natively on Xubuntu (you can install it from [Ubuntu’s packages](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/quodlibet))
- it’s gratis and Free/Open Source
- it uses GStreamer, so it can play MP3 (and all other file types you‘ve GStreamer plugins installed for)
- you can create/import/export playlists
- it’s not a KDE application (it’s based on GTK+)

So it seems to be a 100% match, according to your stated requirements.

It comes (nicely integrated) with the tag editor **Ex Falso**, which I’d also consider really good (I used it to organize all those 30000 tracks).

---

[Screenshot](https://quodlibet.readthedocs.org/en/latest/screenshots.html), showing the album view (which is only one of several views):

> [image: Quod Libet: album view]

---

(I recommended it also as [iTunes alternative on Ubuntu](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/180/60).)

Comment: How does it compare with Amarok?

Comment: @einpoklum: No idea, I never used Amarok. (Thanks for the edit!)

Comment: about to try this, the name sucks by the way lol

Answer (score 4):

I can recommend these two linux audio players:

[gmusicbrowser](http://gmusicbrowser.org/) and [Quod Libet](https://code.google.com/p/quodlibet/)

- support huge libraries (mine is 60.000 tracks with more than 100 GB)
- GTK+ based
- free and open source
- support (auto-)playlists
- support most common audio formats
- GUI is customizable (lots of preconfigured layouts)

Comment: What is your personal experience with both? Do you prefer one? What is the difference between the two?

Comment: Well, it's mostly small details. I personaly prefer gmusicbrowser because of its more powerful playlist widget (grouping, album artwork) and more customizable UI. However Quod Libet has also a couple of strengths (replay gain scanner, more polished UI, nicer documentation). So it's realy just a matter of personal taste and I suggest to try out both.