# Windows Music Player that supports custom lyric

Tags: windows, music

I listen to Japanese songs, so I often need the lyric. I'm using the musicbee player, but I can't use it to display Japanese lyric. I need another music player for Windows that supports adding your own lyric (e.g. in text file).

Comment: So displaying the lyrics in a window is sufficient, they don’t have to scroll synchronized with the song’s playback, right?

Comment: @unor Yes. As it's custom lyric, it'd be difficult to synchronize scroll.

Comment: Well I discovered that musicbee support that too - never noticed that. Hidden in the song information. Sneaky.

Comment: Would be great if you could create an answer, showcasing how musicbee allows it.

Comment: A bit later. A bit of screen captures and a little word... doesn't seem difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Quod Libet**](https://quodlibet.readthedocs.org/) is a cross-platform and free/libre music player (which I also recommend [for huge music collections](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/4081/60), [as iTunes alternative](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/180/60), and [for managing/displaying custom tags](https://superuser.com/a/985015/151741)) that allows to save the lyrics of a song.

To enter/edit the lyrics of a song, you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> (or right-click and select "Information") and select the lyrics tab, which is a simple textarea:

[image: Quod Libet: showing the Japanese lyrics of a song]

The lyrics get saved as text files (a folder for each artist, with a text file for each song, named after the song’s title).

You can even search for songs with certain lyrics:

```
~lyrics = なぜ
```

Comment: I'd love to know how you found it. Great.