# iTunes replacement for Ubuntu, hierarchical playlists and Android syncing?

Tags: music, ubuntu, itunes, audiobook

I've waded through the profusion of "iTunes on Linux" questions on this site and the recommendations (as well as searching Google extensively) but have not seen the combination of features that are important to me.

The keynotes that I see missing (or at least don't see advertised) from most candidates are:

- Excellent support for playlist syncing to Android
- Arbitrarily nested playlists/folders
- Support for audiobooks (which are split into multiple files)
- Support for videos and organization thereof (including multi-gigabyte full movie files)

---

Also, one other thing that I'm not sure exists anywhere (it doesn't really exist in iTunes): organizational features that apply well to a *lecture series*.  (These features would likely apply as well to an audiobook of sequential short stories, if that helps to conceive of it.)  On iTunes I make do with calling the whole lecture series "one audiobook" and then creating playlists in a folder to contain individual lectures within the series.

---

The app must *not* require me to upload all my files, so Google Play is out.  I want control of my files.

Open source would be really nice but is not mandatory.  Open file formats for the playlists and any other metadata *is* mandatory.

---

The closest I have found so far is [Quod Libet](https://quodlibet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), which doesn't appear to support syncing with Android, but looks to have extremely good playlist/organizational capabilities.

Comment: Have you tried [Noise](https://launchpad.net/noise)? Also, if you're thinking about switching to Ubuntu, give [Elementary OS](https://elementary.io) a look; it's based on Ubuntu and uses the same package manager, but it's MUCH sleeker/more refined and also a lot more lightweight.

Comment: @kirbyfan64sos, Elementary OS looks pretty, but is it open source?  No point in switching from Mac (the king of pretty) if I don't get open source.  ...Oh, I see it says it's open source; but how do they have a download price, then?

Comment: It's 100% open-source. The "download price" is just an optional donation; you can put 0. I agree that the home page threw me off the first time, too.

Comment: What exactly means playlist syncing? Syncing the playlist files (without the songs), or syncing the song files in playlists (without the playlists)? If the latter, should it also delete the songs on your Android device if they aren’t contained in any playlists anymore when syncing the next time?

Comment: @unor, both the songs and the playlists, really.  Regarding deletions, that's harder to say.  If every song, including those not on any playlist, could be "checkboxed" separately as to whether to sync to Android or not (and be deleted from Android if no longer "checked")—like iTunes—that would be fine.  If *only* playlisted songs were synced and others were deleted, I would probably make a "Whole Library" playlist just to put the other songs on—but if playing by album/artist weren't built in, I suppose I would construct album/artist playlists anyway and so wouldn't need a "whole library" list.

Comment: @Wildcard open source does not mean that paying is forbidden. :)

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto, true, but it does mean that *required* payments are easily circumvented.  :)  Optional payments makes much more sense.

Comment: @unor, I read into your answers on Quod Libet and I'm going to try it.  It looks like the best bet.  You want to post an answer?  :)

Comment: @Wildcard: I don’t know much about syncing, so I think it might be best if you try QL, and if it meets your needs, you write an answer how it solves your requirements.